# Student t-test (Paired) on multiple matrices with different number of rows using R

Tags: r

I need to use student t Test on the columns two matrices having 21 x 4044 and 36 x 4044 respectively. The columns are identical in both, just the rows vary in length.

Sample code for my example input data

```
mat1 <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol = 5)
mat2 <- matrix(rnorm(125), ncol = 5)

f <- function(x,y){
test <- t.test(x,y, paired=TRUE)
out <- data.frame(stat = test$statistic,
                df   = test$parameter,
                pval = test$p.value,
                conl = test$conf.int[1],
                conh = test$conf.int[2]
                )
return(out)
}


sapply(seq(ncol(mat1)), function(x) f(mat1[,x], mat2[,x]))
```

But is gives the following error

> Error in complete.cases(x, y) : not all arguments have the same length

How to deal with this error?

It works fine for the matrices having same number of rows.

Comment: Do you want paired t-test? It works if you remove `paired=TRUE`.

Comment: Yes I want to do paired t-test.

Comment: You cannot do a paired t-test on this data. You don't have all the pairs. You need to subset it.

Comment: @tmfmnk I performed with unpaired but it gives pval=1 for all the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A paired t-test assumes that you have two results for each entity, so for example, you might measure heart-rate of the same person before and after a race leaving you with reading 1 and reading 2 that are 'paired'. This is what you're achieving with `paired = TRUE`.

In your example, you have differently sized vectors, suggesting that you may not be recording two readings for the same entity, so from here:

- If you have not been collecting pairs of readings from the same subject, switch to `paired = FALSE`.
- If you have been collecting pairs of readings from the same subject then you are missing some readings (by virtue of one column having more readings than the other) and you should remove the cases where you don't have two readings.

Hopefully that makes sense and helps a little.

EDIT: Having just made that change and run your code, I get:

```
stat -0.1336019 -0.8981109 -0.1962769 0.9045503 0.3164153 
df   42.35801   42.9418    38.21301   40.52551  41.40109  
pval 0.8943501  0.3741347  0.8454336  0.3710499 0.7532772 
conl -0.7211962 -1.069044  -0.6361448 -0.363129 -0.5404484
conh 0.6316144  0.4102729  0.5236731  0.9519358 0.7413329
```